# How to translate and rotate an image

Tags: c#, wpf, image, rotation

I  want to rotate and afterwards move an image in c#. The image is in a Canvas . My problem is if you rotate the image with the following

```
private void Schiff_OnMouseWheel(object sender, MouseWheelEventArgs e)
{
    Image _schiff = (Image)sender;

    if (!_schiff.IsMouseCaptured) return;

    Matrix _mat = _schiff.RenderTransform.Value;
    Point _mouse = e.GetPosition(_schiff);

    if (e.Delta > 0)
    {
        _mat.RotateAtPrepend(22.5, _mouse.X, _mouse.Y);
    }
    else
    {
        _mat.RotateAtPrepend(-22.5, _mouse.X, _mouse.Y);
    }

    MatrixTransform _mtf = new MatrixTransform(_mat);
    _schiff.RenderTransform = _mtf;
}
```

or RotateTransform

```
double _angle = 0.0;

_angle += 22.5;
if (_angle == 360.0) _angle = 0.0;

RotateTransform _rotate = new RotateTransform(_angle, _schiff.Width / 2, _schiff.Height / 2);

_schiff.RenderTransform = _rotate;A
```

you just rotate the "picture", but not it's base. So if you want to move the image with Canvas.GetLeft/GetTop, it behaves like it is still not rotated. So if you set the Top/Left-corner, the actual corner of the rotated image isn't placed where I wanted it to be. 
At https://wpf.2000things.com/2013/03/08/772-use-rendertransformorigin-to-change-center-point-for-rotation-transforms/, in the picture you can see what I mean. How can I possibly rotate the "base" with the actual image? I saw it is possible in WinForms, but (how) does it work in WPF?
Thanks in advance, if anything is unclear/wrong I will edit my question.

edit:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/tqhKw.png
You can see the two arrows. They are my images. I rotated them at the center with my above MouseWheelEvent. On the right site there is my movement tab. You can change the speed (the checkbox after "Geschwindigkeit") and then you can either turn left in one section (where - is 0°, | is 22.5° and || is 45° and a section is 69 points in the Canvas) or right and end up in a new location.

Comment: do you use RenderTransformOrigin like in the linked post? also a screenshot would be really helpful to understand what is your objective.

Comment: I set the center point of my rotation with dividing both height and width by 2. But later I also need to rotate the Image at a certain point (left or right). I will edit my post with a screenshot and explain it.

Comment: For me, your question is a little bit hard to understand. This is what I believe to have understood: "The code currently rotates the image around its center, but what you actually want instead is to rotate it around its base, where 'base' means the center of the image's bottom edge." Is this summary correct?

Comment: No. With the base, I mean the initial position of the image. If you look at the link, the image is roated, but there is still a square like the image was when not rotated. That is what I mean with base, because this is practically what the image still is.

Comment: "...with **its** base". Downvoting for lack of effort to formulate the question properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use coordinates relative to the Canvas for transforming the Image element.

With this Image in a Canvas

```
<Canvas x:Name="canvas">
    <Image Width="100"
           Source="C:\Users\Public\Pictures\Sample Pictures\Koala.jpg"
           MouseLeftButtonDown="OnMouseLeftButtonDown"
           MouseLeftButtonUp="OnMouseLeftButtonUp"
           MouseMove="OnMouseMove"
           MouseWheel="OnMouseWheel">
        <Image.RenderTransform>
            <MatrixTransform />
        </Image.RenderTransform>
    </Image>
</Canvas>
```

the code would look like shown below.

The important part is to use `e.GetPosition(canvas)` and not to set the child element's `Canvas.Left`, `Canvas.Top` and `RenderTransformOrigin` properties. All transformations are done with a single Matrix in its `RenderTransform`.

```
private Point? mousePos;

private void OnMouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    ((IInputElement)sender).CaptureMouse();
    mousePos = e.GetPosition(canvas);
}

private void OnMouseLeftButtonUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    ((IInputElement)sender).ReleaseMouseCapture();
    mousePos = null;
}

private void OnMouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (mousePos.HasValue)
    {
        var element = (UIElement)sender;
        var transform = (MatrixTransform)element.RenderTransform;
        var matrix = transform.Matrix;
        var pos = e.GetPosition(canvas);
        matrix.Translate(pos.X - mousePos.Value.X, pos.Y - mousePos.Value.Y);
        transform.Matrix = matrix;
        mousePos = pos;
    }
}

private void OnMouseWheel(object sender, MouseWheelEventArgs e)
{
    var element = (UIElement)sender;
    var transform = (MatrixTransform)element.RenderTransform;
    var matrix = transform.Matrix;
    var pos = e.GetPosition(canvas);
    matrix.RotateAt(e.Delta > 0 ? 22.5 : -22.5, pos.X, pos.Y);
    transform.Matrix = matrix;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. But how should I set coordinates if I want to move the object= For example: I want to move the koala 69 points upwards, and then rotate it again at the top left corner?

Comment: It is already moved in my example. Press the mouse button and drag it. If you want to do it programatically, call `matrix.Translate` with appropriate values.

Comment: How can I get the position of the object if I press a button to move the object? Because GetPosition does not work if I press the button, because the EventArgs changed.

Comment: Excuse me that I have to write again, but it does not for me. Maybe I'm too stupid to do it right, but can you show me code for your example where you just press a button and move the image of the koala for a certain value (maybe 2 or 3) in y, based on the image's actual top left corner?

Comment: Moving an object "based on its top left corner" does not make sense. The whole object is moved by a certain amount. That said, the example is complete and works out of the box. No idea why it does not for you.

Comment: ok I got it, I was just totally stupid. I didn't get it that the value in matrix.Translate is the value for how far you move the object. Thank you for your help.